# How to show dummy progressbar for 2 second?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-progressbar

I just want to **show progress bar** before new activity starts. When I start activity from previous activity, the new screen first shows dummy progress bar (white screen with only progressbar) and after 2 or 3 second starts the new activity.

```
listCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        Intent iMenuList = new Intent(thirdstep.this,  fifthscreen.class);
        startActivity(iMenuList);
    }
});

public class fifthscreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fifthscreen);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it using handler as below:

```
listCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
        int position, long arg3) {
//Display your progressBar here
Handler mHand  = new Handler();
    mHand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(thirdstep.this,  fifthscreen.class);
            //Dismiss progressBar here
            startActivity(iMenuList);
        }
    }, 2000);   
    }
}
});
```

You need to put this code inside `onItemClick` method.

Comment: but i want when user click on listview on thirdscreen  first show blankscreen with only progressbar after 3 or 5 second show new activity

Comment: i want before starting new activity first show progressbar for few second then start new activity

Comment: If you want a total blank screen then you should create a dummy activity only for showing progress bar.

Comment: @smartguy When you put the intent inside Handler.postDelayed as I displayed in my code, it will start with the given delay i.e. 2000 milliseconds in my example code, which is 2 seconds. After this delay it will call the new activity. Start the progress bar when user clicks the list and dismiss it when intent inside handler is called.

Comment: but in ur code u start progressbar on previous activity i want to when user click on new activity from previous activity nothing will show on screen except blank screen with progressbar after finish time of progressbar start new activity

Comment: Ok, do you want to display a progress dialog with spinner or a horizontal loading progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

Ok If your problem is that the activity takes a lot of time to display maybe you want to inflate the xml after the activity is displayed.

Here are the steps:

1. Load a simply Activity and display it on the screen
2. Show a progress bar
3. Inflate a Layout containing all components you need in the activity
4. Manage other initializations
5. Hide the progress bar

Comment: is there any code like firstactivity--->progressbaractivity--->second activity???

Answer (score 0):

You can place an imageView with width and height as fill_parent and change its background images frequently, that will give an illusion of a incrementing progress bar.

Inflate ur layout with another layout having imageView with width and height as fill_parent and a background image of progressBar showing initial value. Then use handlers..

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.progressImage2);

        }
    }, 3200);


new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private class log_in extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        ProgressDialog pDialog;
        int a=0;
       boolean value1;
        @Override
         protected void onPreExecute(){
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Authenticating user...");
            pDialog.show();
         }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
           if(a>300)
           {value1=true;}
           else{a++;
             value1=false;}
            return value1;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean params){
            super.onPostExecute(params);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(params){
                Intent intent=new Intent(LoginActivity.this,menu.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            }
           else{
               error.setText("Wrong password or username combination");
            }

        }

     }
```

just call `new log_in().execute();` where you want to call your next activity

Comment: so before start my fifthscreen is show progressbar??? after finish progressbar is start new activity??

Comment: I didnt get you but call execute in Screen1 and you will see progress bar then asyncTask will switch to screen2

Comment: how long this prgressbar run? tell me 1 more thing i see this solution http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1599

Comment: but this example show error   The method Sleep(int) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}

Comment: I have not given thread in my code but still if you want to use it use in this way

Comment: for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }